# Beamer total number frame always 1

Tags: beamer, totalcount

I'm creating a presentation with beamer, and I'm using the theme Boadilla. My problem is, the total frame number is always 1, whatever the real total frame number, and I don't understand why.

EDIT : I just had to compile two times

Comment: Have you compiled your presentation two times? Otherwise please show us a small example code that reproduces you problem.

Comment: @samcarter This is surely a duplicate, but I'm not sure if I've picked the best candidate. What do you think?